# Transfering Data between Excel Tables of different setup

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that I need transferred into another format. All the information stays the same but it will have a different logic: rows become columns and vice versa. This is a table with a LOT of data so I can't do it manually. What is the easiest way to do this? I'm thinking a formula that will reference the original table and transfer the appropriate cells into the new table. I just can't seem to figure out a good way to do this since I have multiple parameters. ANY help is appreciated!!! Picture of the two tables attached - I'm trying to transfer the yellow dates of the original table into the respective yellow fields of the new table. [image]

Comment: Look into `UnPivot` using `Power Query` aka `Get&Transform` in Excel 2016+

Comment: Unmerge the Vendor header in original table and replace with 3 identical header, then try [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria) (I normally used the last formula) and share us where your stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX($B$4:$J$6,MATCH($L3,$A$4:$A$6,0),MATCH(1,INDEX((N$2=$B$3:$J$3)*($M3=$B$2:$J$2),1,0),0))
```

put that in N3 and drag downwards.

Idea : use the method described in the comment link + use $ to 'lock' the column/row when the formula is dragged.

Have a check.. ( :

Comment: This worked great for the first column (N3:N11). But how do I make it so I can drag it to the right as well? I tried copying the formula into O2 and replacing the N2 part of the formula with O2 but it gives me an #NA error. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! I had to un-merge row 2 vendor fields and just make them 6 individual fields (vendor 1, vendor 1, vendor 1, vendor 2, vendor 2, vendor 2, vendor 3, vendor 3, vendor 3) and slightly modify the formula. Worked like a charm. Thanks so much, I would have never figured this out myself!!!

Comment: I just expand my earlier comments into full solution, the formula ends here, but the learning takes us further... |  Glad it solves. Please click on the 'tick' to mark this question as answered. ( :